# WordPress qTranslate Plus plugin issue, page edit not updating content

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, qtranslate, qtranslate-x

> I just update my wp version from 3.8 to 4.8.1

I am using plugin version Version 2.7.2. No more update is available now.

This plugin was working fine with my old wp version. But now this is creating so many problems

> I am not able to edit pages
>
> Unable to edit permalinks on edit pages.

permalinks now.

What I did:-

```
1) define('QT_SUPPORTED_WP_VERSION', '4.0.1');

2) I set debug true in config file but there is no error
```

Please tell me how can I resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: message on page says updated but did not update content and revision. I mean did not save in database.

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in the new version. Contact plugin author.

Comment: Plugin link, visit plugin site is no more working. it shows not available

Comment: This question is outside the scope of Stack Overflow. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @FluffyKitten, you did not answer the question and just vote down for my question. Are you crazy???

Answer (score 0):

The qTranslate plugin has not been updated in years. Try to install [qTranslate-X](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/) plugin, which is a descendant of qTranslate and it should be compatible if the website used old qTranslate plugin.

Comment: I am using qtranslate-xp not qTranslate

Comment: But the latest qTranslate-x version is 3.4.6.8. Why are you using old version  2.7.2?

Comment: I just tell you I am using qtranslate-xp (qTranslate Plus) and no more update available in admin

Comment: Plugin site:- http://www.primapagina.it/blog/qtranslate-plus/ and https://wpcore.com/plugin/qtranslate-xp

Comment: I also found it on GitHub: https://github.com/gregq/qtranslate-xp. It seems this is also descendant of original qTranslate, but also abandoned. Last update is more than 1000 days old. I still suggest to try qTranslate-X plugin.

Comment: yes, but updated 2 year ago. I can't because I can lost my data. Anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

After searching and debugging a lot on this I found one solution for **page edit problem**. Hope this will help to others if having same problem.

I just follow below steps:-

> From the dashboard, go to Plugins > qTranslate plus > Settings
>
> Click the "Advanced Settings" link In the "Date / Time Conversion"
>
> In the setting group select "Use strftime instead of date". (I was using emulated date function).

Now I have only one issue permalink edit button on edit page not working.

Thanks guys for your help.